# How to "execute" Makefile in Ubuntu to run C program that reads from stdin and outputs to stdout/stderr

Tags: c, makefile, stdout, stdin, stderr

I'm working on a homework problem that reads characters from an **input.txt** file and outputs the first word read into an **output.txt**, the second into an **error.txt**, then the third to **output.txt** again, and so on until it reaches the end of the **input.txt** file.

*I should note this is all done using Ubuntu 18.04*

I was given a custom Makefile and had to edit a C program called **split.c** which would take the **input.txt** through the **stdin** and output to **stdout/stderr**. I can write my C program and have it listed below, however I can't test if it's correct because I do not understand how to run make, how to set up my files correctly and if my C program is correctly reading and outputing as it should.

I have tried running the 'make' command in the terminal but I receive:

*make:  No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.*

I have looked at countless articles on Linux, making 'make files', etc. but I don't know what I'm being asked or what to do so I am at a stand still.  Guidance is greatly appreciated!

The custom makefile looks like this and is called **Makefile.dat**:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall
EXEC=split
SRC=$(EXEC).c
TEXT_DIR=test
TEST_INPUT=$(TEST_DIR)/input.txt
OUT=$(TEST_DIR)/stdout.txt
ERR=$(TEST_DIR)/stderr.txt
EXP_OUT=$(TEST_DIR)/output.txt
EXP_ERR=$(TEST_DIR)/error.txt
TEST_REQS=$(TEST_INPUT) $(EXP_OUT) $(EXP_ERR)
DIFF=diff -bBqa

all:  $(EXEC)

$(EXEC): $(SRC)
   $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(SRC) -o $(EXEC)

.PHONY: test
test: $(TEST_REQS) $(EXEC)
  ./$(EXEC) < $(TEST_INPUT) > $(OUT) 2> $(ERR)
  $(DIFF) $(EXP_OUT) $(OUT)
  $(DIFF) $(EXP_ERR) $(ERR)
  echo TEST PASSED!

.PHONY:  clean
clean:
  $(RM) $(EXEC)
```

And my C program looks like this and is called **split.c**:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
   int input;

   // keep getting characters until end-of-file
   while((input = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF){

     // prints to stdout
     printf(stdout, "%d", input);
     if(input = " ")
       printf("\n");    // encounters whitespace so print new line

     // prints to stderr
     printf(stderr, "%d", input);
     if(input = " ")
       printf("\n");    // encounters whitespace so print new line

    }

    return 0;

 }
```

With the idea being that it takes the input file, then it'll print each letter into it's respective file, and if it encounters a space it'll print a new line before adding the next character into the other file.

For example:

**input.txt** has the text:

```
"How do I do this stuff?"
```

**output.txt** will have:

```
 How
 I
 this
```

**error.txt** will have:

```
 do
 do
 stuff?
```

I fully expect that my C program is missing code.  My thinking when writing the program was, print to stdout, then if whitespace is encounterd, print a new line, then begin printing to stderr, and repeat until EOF is reached.

Comment: Before anything else, the Makefile has to be called Makefile (with no extension) for `make` to find it

Comment: Run `make -f Makefile.data` then `make -f Makefile.dat test`.  Or copy/rename `Makefile.dat` to just `Makefile` (or `makefile`), and then run `make` and `make test` (or `make all test`).  There are lots of ways to get to the required result.

Comment: @thisisbenmanley :  Not at all:   `make -f makefile.dat test`

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : Since `split` is a dependency of the target `test` is it not sufficient to make the `test` target alone?

Comment: @Clifford sorry, I messed up my phrasing - the Makefile has to be called Makefile (with no extension) for the exact command "`make`" to automatically find it

Comment: @Clifford: yes, you could just run `make test` with the appropriate `makefile` present.

Comment: Some updates...when I run `make` I get `make: *** No rule to make target 'split.c', needed by 'split'.  Stop`.  When I run `make -f makefile.dat test` I receive `make:  Makefile.dat:  No such file or directory`.  And when I run `make test` I receive `make: *** No rule to make target 'text/input.txt', needed by 'test'.  Stop.`  Any idea what that means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either rename `Makefile.dat` to `Makefile`, like this:

```
mv Makefile.dat Makefile
make
```

or run `make` with the `-f` option and an argument of your `Makefile`:

```
make -f Makefile.dat
```

Make sure all your files (`split.c`, `test/input.txt`, `Makefile`) are present in the same directory as the `Makefile`, otherwise this won't work.

Note some issues with your C code:

```
if(input = " ")
```

is wrong. First of all, it's assigning a string with a space in it `" "` (which is a pointer to `char`) to `input`, instead of checking if `input` is a space character.

To fix the issue, use this:

```
if(input == ' ')
```

in both cases.

Comment: This did work in getting `make` to execute, however now I think I have a problem in my `split.c` file.  In particular I get these two warnings: `split.c:11:11: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]` on the = part of my if statement.  And it also gives out `split.c:11:5: warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]` on the input portion of the if statement.  This is on both If statements in my program.